# "Server not found" website dns suddenly not working

Tags: dns, web-hosting

Our Site, www.bulletnewsdeals.com, results in "Server Not Found", Ping is failing saying host not found.  The site worked up until last night and nothing was changed. There is a screen shot of the dns settings attached. Any help would be apprciated....[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you contacted whoever hosts the site for you? You've obviously got net access to post your query so it looks like the problem is at their end.

Comment: Sorry, it's working now, it was some sorta glitch with the host :)